# Extract rasterlayer from extent class

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, extract

I used `extract()` function to get remote sensing image cell value.The same code to process tif file produce error message. Code as follows：

```
r1 <- raster("2000_2605_1.1_km_monthly_NDVI.tif")
polygon_mus <- extent(c(107, 111, 37, 40))
cell <- extract(r1, polygon_mus)
```

This *.tif is a output file from MODI hdf file with MRT. The process result is as follow:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function extent?for signature ?NULL"?
```

Where is the error? I seem to be missing it.

Comment: Did you check if polygon_mus and r1 overlay?  (e.g. by plotting both together)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can only guess without a reproducable example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ha~It's amazing~Thanks for your help Iris

Comment: The problem is overlay error, but now I have some problems to make them have same extent.I am a student ,so I have too much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your raster and your polygon do not overlap. If they do:

```
> r1 = raster(extent(c(107,110,38,40)))
> polygon_mus <- extent(c(107, 111, 37, 40))
> cell <- extract(r1, polygon_mus)
```

Then that works. If they don't:

```
> r1 = raster(extent(c(112,114,38,40)))
> cell <- extract(r1, polygon_mus)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

I get your error message. Check the `extent(r1)` to see where it is. I'll bet it doesn't overlap the extent you defined in `polygon_mus`.

Comment: The r1 is a rasterlayer with coordinate,but the polygon_mus is a custom extent class without any coordinate.I try to reproject polygon_mus to the same project with r1,but got error message :                                               
**Error in rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  : 
  no arguments in initialization list**

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the polygon_mus's extent as follow: > polygon_mus class : **Extent xmin : 107 xmax : 111 ymin : 37 ymax : 40 **but, the extent of r1 is **> extent(r1) class : Extent xmin : 8895604 xmax : 10007555 ymin : 3335852 ymax : 4447802**